# How to measure performance of awaiting asynchronous operations?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, performance-testing, c#-5.0

I have a Windows Service that reads from multiple `MessageQueue` instances. Those messagequeues all run their own `Task` for reading messages. Normally, after reading a message, the work of an I/O database is done. I've found articles claiming it's a good idea to use async on I/O operations, because it would free up threads. I'm trying to simulate the performance boost of using async  I/O opertations in a Console application.

## The Console application

In my test environment, I have 10 queues. `GetQueues()` returns 10 different `MessageQueue` instances.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var isAsync = Console.ReadLine() == "Y";
    foreach (var queue in queueManager.GetQueues())
    {
        var temp = queue;
        Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessagesForQueue(temp, isAsync));
    }

    while (true)
    {
        FillAllQueuesWithMessages();
        ResetAndStartStopWatch();
        while(!AllMessagesRead())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All messages read in {0}ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

static async Task ReceiveMessagesForQueue(MessageQueue queue, bool isAsync)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var message = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(queue.BeginReceive(), queue.EndReceive);

        if (isAsync)
            await ProcessMessageAsync(message);
        else
            ProcessMessage(message);
    }
}
```

### Async message processing

Uses await on `Task.Delay()`, so should release current `Thread`

```
static async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Message message)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    BurnCpu();
}
```

### Sync message processing

waits on `Task.Delay()`, so shouldn't release current `Thread`

```
static void ProcessMessage(Message message)
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    BurnCpu();
}
```

In the end, results are equal. Am I missing something here?

#### Edit 1

I'm measuring overall time using `stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds`. I Fill all queues using `FillAllQueuesWithMessages()` with 10, 100, 10000 or more messages.

#### Edit 2

`ReceiveMessagesForQueue()` returns `Task` instead of `void` now.

#### Edit 3 (fix)

This test does show me performance improvement now. I had to make `BurnCpu()` take more time. While `Task.Delay()` is being awaited, `BurnCPU()` can use the released thread to process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `async-await` doesn't speed up the time it takes to execute a single operation, it just means that **you don't have a thread waiting doing nothing**.

In your case `Task.Delay` will take a second no matter what but here:

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

You *have* a thread that sits and waits for the second to end while here:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

You *don't*. You are still asynchronously waiting (hence, `await`) but no thread is being used which means better scalability.

In `async-await` you get the performance boost because your app can do the same with less threads, or do more with the same threads. To measure that you need to have a lot of `async` operations concurrently. Only then will you notice that the `async` option utilizes `CPU` resources better than the synchronous one.

---

More info about freeing threads here [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: I understand I'm freeing up threads. Here's what I can't spin my head around: If I have a 4-core processor running 10 parallel processes reading messages from a queue, shouldn't it be thread switching when using await on `Task.Delay()`? I would like to use the thread that has been released. If I release a thread for 1 of 10 processes, why isn't one of the others using that thread?

Comment: @Noseratio I changed my method to return Task instead of void. This doesn't solve my problem, but it's learn-full either way.

Comment: @annemartijn, in the console app, the code after `await Task.Delay()` will most likely continue on another thread. You'll see that if you add `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString())`  after `await Task.Delay()`. But I'm not sure I follow your logic inside the `foreach` loop. What you do there is *fire-and-forget*, you don't track or await the completion of the tasks you're starting, plus `Task.Run` is certainly redundant there.

Comment: I actually see results now. If `Task.Delay()` takes 200 ms and `BurnCpu()` burns CPU for around 300 ms, I see an overall improvement of ~20% if I'm using `await`. Can I only achieve this time boost if I'm using CPU after `await`? I thought, that if I'm using await, another process could start receiving a message since I have 10 parallel processes and only 4 processor cores.

Comment: @annemartijn When you say processes do you mean threads? To get an improvement out of using async-await you need to have both CPU work and IO (or other async) work concurrently (in your app). That way when a thread gets "blocked" on IO it can go and do other CPU work instead of idly waiting.

Comment: So basically, my results proof your point. If I'm doing CPU work and IO, I see performance improvement when using `await` instead of blocking the current `Thread`. But shouldn't I also be able to do more concurrent I/O calls if I'm freeing up threads? In my questions case I'm parallelly reading 10 messagequeues. I have 4 cores on my testing machine, so I can only parallelly process 4 reads a time. Using await I'd say you free up a thread, so another messagequeue can start reading? I know I'm probably wrong, but I would like to know why.

Comment: @annemartijn you're not wrong. Using "thread-less async" allows you to do more IO (or async) calls concurrently because it doesn't use up resources and threads can do CPU work in the meantime. That's what scalabilty means.

Comment: Why isn't my overall time less if I remove `BurnCpu()`. I'm starting 10 parallel tasks at the start of my application that read messages and process this message using async I/O, in this case `Task.Delay()`. I'd say using await you can have 10 `Task.Delay()` concurrently awaiting, without await only 4 since I have a 4-core processor and 4 threads are blocked at `Task.Delay().Wait()`.

Comment: @annemartijn That's not really the case. When a thread is blocked (with Thread.Sleep for example) the CPU cuts it off and does a context switch. Also, you have more than just 4 threads, and the thread pool can create more if it needs them.

Comment: @I3arnon So basically you won't see a noticeable difference using await unless you combine CPU intensive work and I/O work?

Comment: Yes. Async doesn't shorten your asynchronous operations. They take as long as needed. But it frees up threads so you can fire more async operations or use CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

You're still running each task in its own thread from the thread pool - as you're using the default task scheduler. If you want to see performance imporvement, you'll need to make sure several tasks are performed on the same thread.

Also, with 20 parallel tasks, you're probably not going to see any difference. Try it with 2,000 tasks.