# Measuring performance gains with async-await

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, task

There are numerous articles, discussions and questions on topic of performance gain with async await in the scenario when you thread keeps waiting on external calls (database, network I/O, disk I/O). I would like to how these performance gains could be measured. What could be the right metrics to be measure in these cases? May be any code examples or samples to measure it?

Comment: Specifics of this question aside, this is really a question of how to performance test C# code in general.  For which you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359829/how-to-measure-performance-of-awaiting-asynchronous-operations

Comment: You'd probably want to limit the number of thread pool threads (`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`) before doing any sync-vs-async benchmarking.