# Fill GridViews with Entity Framework Asynchronously

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I have a form containing 4 gridviews. I would like to fill these gridviews with objects I query thanks to entity Framework. The problem is that the UI gets stuck while they load. I thus tried to make the query asynchronous but it isn't working. I have tried to do it several ways but my current solution looks like this

```cs
        private async void SwiftCheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radGridViewLast7Days.DataSource = await MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.ReturnLast7DaysAsync();
            radGridViewAmount.DataSource = await MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsAsync();
            radGridViewAmountBySwift.DataSource = await MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsByTypeAsync();
            radGridViewAmountBySender.DataSource = await MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsBySenderAsync();

            //Code to adapt the gridviews layout after data has been bound
            this.radGridViewAmountBySender.BestFitColumns();

        }
```

I bind the data in the load event because from my understanding I cannot use await in the constructor.
I then use await on each task because Entity Framework isn't thread safe. So if I understood properly, I can't launch each task at the same time and then await them all ?

This is one of the codes that returns the list of objects

```cs
        public static async Task<List<MsMessage>> ReturnLast7DaysAsync()
        {
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-7);

            using (var db = new SveulumeContext())
            {

                var query = db.MsMessages
                    .Where(u => u.Created >= currentDate);

                return await query.ToListAsync();               

            }
        }
```

The code works and binds the gridViews properly but the UI still blocks during the whole process. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @SachaDieryck: What is your database provider?

Comment: @iSpain17: The asynchronous LINQ usage is correct.

Comment: @iSpain17 I don't care that my users interact with the grids but the application does other things and I don't want it to block while the querying is going on.
I tried using background workers but then I got the error "Control "" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on".

So I guess the best solution would be to launch a background thread that does the querying, await its results and then bind the data in the main thread ?
I guess my LINQ queries don't need to be Async anymore if I do that ?

Comment: @StephenCleary it is an oracle DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-wait-properly/29034291#29034291), Oracle does not support asynchronous queries in its .NET library. So, the way you're doing asynchronous LINQ is correct; it's just that Oracle doesn't support it. This is why you're seeing the queries run synchronously rather than asynchronously.

To get the code off the UI thread, you can use `Task.Run`. I recommend also adding a comment to the code, since it *looks* wrong:

```
// Task.Run is necessary because Oracle does not support async: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-wait-properly/29034291#29034291
radGridViewLast7Days.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.ReturnLast7DaysAsync());
```

On a side note, EF does support multiple simultaneous queries **if** they each use their own db context. Since your methods do use their own db context, you can load all these queries simultaneously:

```
private async void SwiftCheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Task.Run is necessary because Oracle does not support async: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-

  var last7DaysTask = Task.Run(() => MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.ReturnLast7DaysAsync());
  var compareAmountsTask = Task.Run(() => MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsAsync());
  var compareAmountsByTypeTask = Task.Run(() => MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsByTypeAsync());
  var compareAmountsBySenderTask = Task.Run(() => MonitoringToolCore.SwiftQueries.CompareAmountsBySenderAsync());
  await Task.WhenAll(last7DaysTask, compareAmountsTask, compareAmountsByTypeTask, compareAmountsBySenderTask);
  radGridViewLast7Days.DataSource = await last7DaysTask;
  radGridViewAmount.DataSource = await compareAmountsTask;
  radGridViewAmountBySwift.DataSource = await compareAmountsByTypeTask;
  radGridViewAmountBySender.DataSource = await compareAmountsBySenderTask;

  //Code to adapt the gridviews layout after data has been bound
  this.radGridViewAmountBySender.BestFitColumns();
}
```

Comment: The explanation is clear and I just tried the code and it works, thank you !