# Unexpected different results using Task.WhenAll and Parallel.ForEach with an Entity Framework Core DataContext

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-core

Given this Entity Framework Core snippet

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope()) {
    var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEFCoreDataContext>();
//  async operations on ctx and entity (see below for entity)
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And a List<> of entities I want to use it in a concurrent way. I first tried

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(list, async entity => {
    <snippet>
});
```

This fails in SaveChangesAsync for concurrency issues (DataContext).
Then I tried

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    list.Select(
        async entity => {
            <snippet>
        }
    )
);
```

And this succeeds.
I know they do things differently (ForEach partitions the input list, ...), however I would like to understand while the Foreach version fails.

Comment: @IvanStoev Task.WhenAll does actually work with an IEnumerable<Task>, no need to materialize it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

Comment: What is the target database? Could it be [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-wait-properly) by any chance?

Comment: database is  SQL Server

Comment: As a side note, the `Parallel.ForEach` method [is not async-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137393/parallel-foreach-and-async-await). Feeding the `Parallel.ForEach` with async delegates is a bug. It doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: A possible reason that the `await Task.WhenAll(...` succeeds is that the asynchronous operations are actually performed synchronously, and so they are serialized. Could you verify that the `SaveChangesAsync` operations are indeed executed concurrently, using logging or other means?

Comment: In know it is not async friendly, however this doesn't make it a bug! "async doesn't work well with ForEach" is not equivalent to "async in ForEach is a bug". If it is, the compiler should forbid it.

Comment: DbContext is not thread safe, do you know that?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that's why the first thing in the snippet is create a new scope, so that every concurrent operation works in its own context.

Comment: *"This fails in SaveChangesAsync for concurrency issues (DataContext)."* Could you include in the question more info about the error? (exception type and message)

Comment: I see, looks correct. Anyway when i see such attempts to work with EF - something went wrong earlier.  Why you just not call Task.Run and dd tasks to the list?

Comment: "*A [software bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) is an error, flaw or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways.*" So whether the Parallel.ForEach+async is a bug depends on whether you expect it to launch the asynchronous operations and return without awaiting them, and so without propagating any failures, rendering ineffective any try-catch around the parallel loop. I bet that this was not your intention! 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-5.0 there is no indication that "Feeding the Parallel.ForEach with async delegates is a bug". If we call ForEach with an int instead of an action, the compiler clearly indicates the error, but it doesn't with and async. There is certainly a bug, but not where you indicated.

Comment: @TheodorZouliasThe error is an exception with message like "SaveChanges expected to affect x rows but instead it affected y"

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to understand while the Foreach version fails.

`ForEach` doesn't understand `async` lambdas. Since the `ForEach` parameter is of type `Action`, the `async` lambda is converted to an `async void` method. One of the [problems with `async void` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) is that it's not easy for the calling code to determine when it has completed, so the `ForEach` loop appears to end "early" - before the `async void` lambdas have completed.

`async void` was added to the language to enable `async` event handlers, but this is not an event handler, so it's not correct to use `async void` lambdas here.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this seems to be in need of improvement on the .NET side, as for example:

- Compiler: detect and forbid async void use (direct or as result of conversion as in this case) outside of async event handlers.
- Documentation: clearly state in the official documentation that Parallel.ForEach should not be called with async handlers.
- Documentation: if using async is possible but needs particular attention, show example(s) of working/correct use.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Theodor Zoulias's comment, it turns out that ForEach seems to be designed to work only for synchronous handlers, while a ForEachAsync is on the way.
Regardless Microsoft willing, it would be a good thing if the C# compiler pops an error when an async handler is passed as ForEach input

Comment: I don't know if Microsoft would be willing to add a warning in the documentation of `Parallel.ForEach` (you could [try](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/new/choose) to make it happen if you want), but the good news is that a new API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946) will be probably included in the upcoming .NET 6, designed specifically for accepting acync delegates. Hopefully this new addition will make the `Parallel.ForEach` less of a pit of failure that it currently is.