# Trigger Task method rapidly

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Command receiver:

```cs
public override async ValueTask Execute(){
    // my code here
    // this is boardcast command
    // attempt #1
    Parallel.ForEach(lists, async list => { await DoSomething(); });

    // attempt #2
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(ulong id in ids) tasks.Add(DoSomething());
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

DoSomething():

```cs
public async Task DoSomething(){
    Task<abc> Request = API.RequestSomething();
    // attempt #1
    await Request.ContinueWith(Callback => {
        // Do something (long time...) , eg: update database, update all client data etc.
    });

    // attempt #2
    await Request.ContinueWith(Callback => {
        // .....
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}
```

**Question is** : If client sent command to receiver rapidly (about 100 commands per seconds), how can I handle this without (or low) delay, or how can I make my task function (`Task DoSomeThing();`) run in parallel

I have tested my code and it works fine. But I would like your advice if there is a better way. Or is there any mistake that I'm missing? (I haven't tested it with multiple commands per second).

Comment: "I have tested my code and it works fine." - in that case, everything more is premature optimization.

Comment: Be aware that the `Parallel.ForEach` [is not async friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915707/unexpected-different-results-using-task-whenall-and-parallel-foreach-with-an-ent/67923412#67923412). Also combining `ContinueWith` with `await` [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965200/difference-between-await-and-continuewith), since these two mechanisms accomplish the same thing. Use one or the other, and preferably `await`.

Comment: I tried many methods Until I tried this method, it works, but I don't know if there are any other cases that will cause my code to not work properly. but thanks everyone for the quick replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, `Parallel` should not be used with `async` methods, so the `Task.WhenAll` approach is the correct solution for asynchronous concurrency:

```
public override async ValueTask Execute() {
  var tasks = ids.Select(id => DoSomething()).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Regarding your implementation, [do not use `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html):

```
public async Task DoSomething() {
  var Callback = await API.RequestSomething();
  // Do something (long time...) , eg: update database, update all client data etc.
}
```