# WPF ViewModel AsyncCommand Freeze whole UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm developing a straightforward application that features a single datagrid responsible for loading data through MediatR. To facilitate data refresh functionality upon a button click, I've implemented an AsyncCommand, drawing inspiration from a particular [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands). However, upon triggering the refreshBtnCommand, I've encountered an issue where the entire UI freezes for a few seconds everytime reload the data or swap between different pages. I'm uncertain about the source of this problem and would greatly appreciate any solutions or guidance to rectify it.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public IAsyncRelayCommand DownloadTextCommand { get; private set; }
    private readonly IRepositoryManager _RepositoryManager;
    public MainPageViewModel(IRepositoryManager RepositoryManager)
    {
        RefreshBtnCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(runTest);
    }
    public async Task runTest()
    {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    if (i++ == int.MaxValue) break;
                }
            });
    
            await _RepositoryManager.TestRepository.Test();
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Grid>
  <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding DownloadTextCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Repository

```
public class TestRegisterRepository : ITestRegisterRepository
{
    private new readonly ModelContext _modelContext;
    public TestRegisterRepository (ModelContext repositoryContext)
    {
        _modelContext = repositoryContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<DataTable>> Test() {
        return await Task.Run(() => this._modelContext.DataTable.Take(1000).ToListAsync());
//return await this._modelContext.DataTable.Take(1000).ToListAsync(); //Freeze UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example, i.e., something others can run in a debugger?

Comment: @StephenCleary Surely. I have updated my post to a simplified example. I think it could be reproducible just by adding an EF core context.
I finally found that if I commented out "await _RepositoryManager.TestRepository.Test()" in runTest, the UI is running fine with no freeze. But if keeps it, it will freeze the whole UI even if I use ToListAsync() in the TestRegisterRepository.Test method.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle 12c and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.11 nuget package

Comment: Last time I checked, Oracle doesn't support asynchronous EF queries. So you'll need to wrap then in `Task.Run` as a workaround. You can verify this fairly easily by capturing the `Task` returned from `ToListAsync` and seeing if `IsCompleted` is ever `false`. I suspect it's always `true` (i.e., Oracle always runs synchronously even when you call asynchronous APIs).

Comment: You are right, Stephen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016698/can-the-oracle-managed-driver-use-async-await-properly