# What's the difference between Task.Run and async Task in this context?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Could someone please explain to me what is the difference in the behaviour of the two code samples below?
Which one is better/safer?
This is a snippet from a Repository implementation.

**Task.Run**

```
    public Task<TDocument> FindByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var objectId = new ObjectId(id);
            var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, objectId);
            return _collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        });
    }
```

**Async Task**

```
    public async Task<TDocument> FindByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        var objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(doc => doc.Id, objectId);
        return await _collection.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await

Comment: Depending on who you ask, the first `FindByIdAsync` (with `Task.Run`) might violate the guideline about [not exposing asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Run`, as said in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0):

> Queues the specified work to run on the `ThreadPool` and returns a task or `Task<TResult>` handle for that work.

I.e. in this case it will force the execution of all the code on the thread pool. Usually `Task.Run` is used for CPU-bound workloads, for example if `FindByIdAsync` is executed within some single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` (for example in UI thread of a desktop app) and code before `SingleOrDefaultAsync` call is computational-heavy it can lead to UI freezes which is not desirable (also it will handle cases when `SingleOrDefaultAsync` is not "truly async").

On the other hand if you are calling this method in "vanilla" ASP.NET Core which does not have synchronization context there is not much point in using `Task.Run` in this case and the second approach should be preferable (it should be more performant, though not that much noticable in a lot of cases).

Also assuming that this is code used to query some database/storage and client highly likely is "truly async" (note that [there are some nasty exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034291/2501279)) then there is not much point in using first one over the second one.

See also:

- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Asynchronous programming doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)
- [Task asynchronous programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model)
- [Recognize CPU-bound and I/O-bound work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work)

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is suitable when you want to parallelize CPU-bound work. However, in the context of asynchronous programming, it's not the most efficient approach because it introduces additional overhead by starting a new task and running the code on a different thread.

The second approach is more efficient and is the recommended way to handle asynchronous operations. It doesn't introduce unnecessary context switching or additional thread overhead, making it a better choice for asynchronous code.

In summary, the `async/await` approach is generally better and safer for handling asynchronous operations in a Repository or any other asynchronous code.

For more details: [Task.Run vs Async Await](https://www.hexacta.com/task-run-vs-async-await/)